# Readability of SQL requests. Is there an upper limit on the number of nested functions in sql request

Tags: sql-server

I am new to SQL. I want to feed data from SQL to my program. Right now an SQL request is generated by concatenating multiple statements. Is there a limit on the number of nested functions in excel (similar to the seven nested functions per formula limit in Excel)? Or will it try to execute arbitrary complex statement?

---

"It depends basically on the DBMS you're using. All of them have some sort of max SQL statement length limit." - Can you please share the information about these limits? I am interested in SQL server, but limits of other DBMS might be of interest to other SO visitors.

Comment: It depends basically on the DBMS you're using. All of them have some sort of max SQL statement length limit.

Comment: The fact that you are asking this question indicates that your overall approach might have room for improvement.

Comment: I am using SQL server 2012 and I expect up to 15 keywords in the statement. I am not hitting a limit yet, but I want to avoid a nasty surprise.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "up to 15 _keywords_"? Even without a join it's probably possible to use 15 keywords in a single query. Or are you actually talking about "15 _tables_"?

Comment: I am talking about keywords like "select", "from", "where", etc.

Comment: Can you please explain the reason of downvoting? I am new to Stackoverflow and it would help to know  what I did wrong. Is the question off-topic? Or tagged incorrectly? Or offensive?

Comment: Maybe it's the not showing any research -part or being unclear. Nested function and a keyword are totally different things, so it's quite hard to understand what you're actually asking.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords-in-java/8881376 - this is RTFM, indeed. 2K upvotes. I did research the question and I didn't find anything about the SQL limits. I could research longer, but then what is the point of SO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be configured using MAX_SQL_LENGTH. On SQLLite you would use SQLLITE_MAX_SQL_REQUEST.

sqlite.org/limits.html has a great article on other limits. Also check
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126380/Writing-Readable-SQL for a style reference.

Comment: The question is tagged SQL Server. There is no such setting in SQL Server.